# Insert multiple values in MySql Column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have information from a form that i would like to enter into a MySQL DB, The normal insert works great for me but I would like to combine two text fields into one Column in the database.

Below is the current code I use to insert values to MySQL

```
$make = $_POST['make'];
$model = $_POST['model'];

UPDATE gs.gs_objects SET
    vin = '".$vin."',
    plate_number = '".$engine."',
    model = '".$make."' '".$model."', //I am not sure if this is correct as it keeps giving me error!!
    installer = '".$installer."'
WHERE imei = '$imei'
```

I am trying to add the make and model into on Column **Ford Ranger** as it is in two separate fields in my form

Comment: If you run such a query, be sure to check for error messages thrown by MySQL - it will inform you quickly whether that works or not

Comment: Also you should use [prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have unwanted single quotes here :

```
model = '".$make."' '".$model."'
```

Should be written as :

```
model = '".$make." ".$model."'
```

Query :

```
$query = 
    "UPDATE gs.gs_objects SET
        vin = '".$vin."',
        plate_number = '".$engine."',
        model = '".$make." ".$model."', 
        installer = '".$installer."'
    WHERE imei = '$imei'";
```

NB : anyone on SO will strongly suggest to [**use prepared statements and parameterized queries**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), to protect your code from SQL injection and make your queries more readable and maintainable. Such typo is far much easier to detect when using parameterized queries.

Answer (score 2):

The best is to have two different columns (it gives more option if you want to select a specific information). But if you want to keep all the information in one column, you can do it in a variable to avoid concatenation in a query.

```
$make = $_POST['make'];
$model = $_POST['model'];

$complete_model = $make.' '.$model;

UPDATE gs.gs_objects SET
                vin = '".$vin."',
                plate_number = '".$engine."',
                model = '".$complete_model."',
                installer = '".$installer."'
                WHERE imei = '".$imei."'
```